# Ready country list for Database?

Tags: php

I want the user to enter their full address including a dropdown list of countries and cities that are updated based on the country selected.

Do I really have to manual create a country database table as well as all possible cities table and then make a giant php check to match the two?

I am sure there is a smarter way of doing it, but I could not seem to find one! 
Later I will be using the country and city to filter the results that are displayed on the page.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you taken the time to search for existing lists/tables that you can simply import?

Comment: you can write a script to parse it from some source

Comment: I have searched but things like "php country dropdown list database" but didn't really find helpful links

Comment: Someone has wrote it for you: [http://www.sudhir.pro/v/sBc](http://www.sudhir.pro/v/sBc)

Comment: localhost won't let me import anything over 2mb... that database is over 80mb!

Comment: @Gadgetster No list of EVERY city for EVERY country is going to be under 2MB

Comment: I guess I can't test using localhost then.. Okay thank you!

Comment: I suggest, you to checkout this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/turalus/openDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*search search search*

goto http://www.geonames.org you can find complete list of cities in the world

In particular, you can search over the [dump list](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/).

[Sql dump of all the Countries, Country Codes, Phone codes](https://gist.github.com/adhipg/1600028)

Comment: I am searching for a dump that has country, region, and city but can't find them unless they are a ready sql file over 80mb which I cannot upload to localhost

Comment: Link to get the complete database for countries with phone codes here: http://www.infomazing.net/blog/database-country-table-with-sql-insert-statements